# Why javax.swing instead of java.swing?

Tags: java, swing, package, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why import javax.swing.* why not import java.swing.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004759/why-import-javax-swing-why-not-import-java-swing)

This may seem as a stupid question, but why was the Java Swing Framework(a.k.a Java Foundation Classes) put in the **javax** package instead of the **java** package like the Abstract Window Toolkit?

```
import javax.swing.*
```

instead of

```
import java.swing.*
```

What is the difference between **java** and **javax**?

Comment: @Thilo thanks. sorry for my post, I didn't know there was already a question on this.

Comment: Can someone please vote for closing before this question gets downvoted? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prefix *javax* is used for a package of Java standard extension.

Answer (score 2):

Java swing package was not in the first release of java. It's added latter version of java. So it's an extension for java. X stands for extension