# Inheriting JFrame violates Generalization

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, jframe, actionlistener

While developing java stand alone applications , some developers tend to extend JFrame class and Implement(realize) some actionlistener interface . Does it not violate The generalization concept in oops and also abstraction . Does it not violate Single responsibility principle too.

[EDIT] By violate The generalization concept in oops , i mean  "is-a" relationship becomes void.
Inherit a class changed to extend a class

Comment: What according to you is the generalization concept and abstraction? You may be right abut the single responsibility principle violation but I need to see the code to confirm this.

Comment: I'm not ready with the code yet.  But abstraction means making the object do things and contains things ,that is relevant to the object. And to give a UI to any executor program which we do by inheriting JFrame we violate generalization. Is 'nt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This frequently seen anti-pattern poses several problems:

```
class Application extends JFrame implements ActionListener {}
```

- Given a [preference for composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance), an `Application` might *have a* `JFrame`, but it should only *extend* `JFrame` to override its existing functionality.
- Implementing an interface in this way can lead to [*leaking* `this` *in a constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9851813/230513). This compounds the problem of ensuring that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Regarding [*generalization*](https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance), a `JFrame` is a *specialization* of `Window`, used as a [*top-level container*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). Don't confuse the [containment hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) with the [class hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).
- Regarding [*single responsibility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), the `JFrame` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) shows a coherent derivation, despite Swing's [history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004759/230513) and [cross-platform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) abstraction.

Implementing a control interface, such as `ActionListener`, may be convenient for a [self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but a complex application will likely need more than one [controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513). An example using [jmapviewer](/questions/tagged/jmapviewer) is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016425/230513). See also [*Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets*](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I didnt confuse with containment hierarchy, but was curious if IS-A relationship being violated as a result?

Comment: Sorry if I seemed [sententious](https://www.google.com/search?q=sententious) about potential confusion. Based on the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and [history](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2004759/230513), I would say that the `JFrame` derivation  is reasonably coherent. Do you see a specific anomaly?

Comment: It will accept the answer if you can brief about vioaltion of single responsibility principle

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing and hard to understand, because you're using strange terminology. These sentences are correct and mean something:

- a class extends another class
- a class implements an interface
- a class inherits methods from its parent class

These sentences are inappropriate, unclear:

- a class inherits another class
- violate generalization concept

Especially without code, I can only guess what you're asking, but I try to answer anyway:

- a class that extends JFrame and at the same time implements an action listener interface, violates the single responsibility principle by being 2 things at once
- a class that extends JFrame and at the same time contains some logic not related to displaying or configuring a JFrame, violates the single responsibility principle by doing 2 things at the same time. It also violates good separation of model-view-controller
- a class that extends JFrame, but in terms of its behavior / implementation it's not mainly a JFrame but something else, then it violates the abstraction of a JFrame, and it shouldn't extend JFrame but possibly contain it instead

Comment: So what about Abstraction and is-a relationship ? Will only MVC seperation be violated? Thanks for the response. And for correction

Comment: You're right, yes, good abstraction will be violated too. I added one more point in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the details.